# php decoding image not working properly

Tags: php

I have, with the help of a tutorial, created a php file that from an encoded String saves it in a file but there is an issue where it's not decoding, I can't figure why the `base64_decode` doesn't do it's part i have even checked the php manual and all seems fine, this is the php code

```
<?php
$name = $_REQUEST["name"];
$image = $_REQUEST["image"];

$decodedImage = base64_decode("$image");
file_put_contents("pictures/" . $name . ".JPG", $decodedImage);
?>
```

[image: Image used for test]

Comment: Remove the quotes from around "$image" in `base64_decode`?

Comment: can you provide us an example of `$image?`

Comment: tried it but it didn't work

Comment: i will edit  put one the images i use for test

Comment: so, what's `$image`'s value?

Comment: i have an android project that takes care of the encoding part i can upload the code if needed

Comment: I'll settle of `die($image);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another way to do it:

```
$decodedImage = base64_decode($image);
if (!$file = fopen("pictures/" . $name . ".JPG", 'wb')) {
    throw new Exception('Failed to open');
}
if (fwrite($file, $decodedImage) === FALSE) {
    throw new Exception('Failed to write');
}
fclose($file);
```

Comment: it didn't work, this is the file it provides. https://i.gyazo.com/a6e769baf274db612c5a876cf95f0388.png

Comment: @IKeepForgettingAccsMail if it did not work, you should tell me wich exception did you get

Comment: actually it worked when i tried with a static image there was `image/jpeg;base64,...` that part caused the image not to be decoded i will  split the string & do the deal thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Remove quote arround your variable

```
<?php
 $name = $_REQUEST["name"];
 $image = $_REQUEST["image"];

 $decodedImage = base64_decode($image);
 file_put_contents("pictures/" . $name . ".JPG", $decodedImage);
 ?>
```

Comment: `foo($bar)` and `foo("$bar")` are the same thing